# Accessing an injected object from inside of a class in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I want to re-open a class and define a new 'class' function. Inside this new function, I want to have access to an injected property. Is there a way to do this?

Injecting dependency

```
export default {
  name: 'userManager',

  initialize: function(container, application){
    var userManager = Ember.Object.extend({
      //Some stuff
    });

    application.register('manager:user', userManager);
    application.inject('route', 'userManager', 'manager:user');
    application.inject('model', 'userManager', 'manager:user');
    application.inject('controller', 'userManager', 'manager:user');
  }

};
```

Re-opening a class to add a class method

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Person = Ember.Object.extend({});

Person.reopenClass({
  //how do I access an injected object here?
})

export default Invoice;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with?

```
Person.reopenClass({
  someMethod: function() {
    var userManager = this.get('userManager');
  }
})
```

Comment: I am not sure, but this may only work on the class only after `init` has been called